# Console reports "sandboxd deny mach-lookup" ... Should I modify system.sb?

Tags: terminal, time-machine, backup, console, sandbox

I'm getting two errors in the console at the same time TimeMachine is running and taking FOREVER to make any progress.

```
1/4/13 9:41:38.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(5838) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
```

The second entry is :

```
 mdworker32(5837) deny mach-lookup com.apple.PowerManagement.control (import 
 fstype:hfs fsflag:480D000 flags:200000056 diag:0 uti:com.microsoft.excel.openxml.addin
  plugin:/Library/Spotlight/Microsoft Office.mdimporter - find suspect file using: sudo mdutil -t 861170)
```

It has the following details:

```
Process:         mdworker32 [5837]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker32
Load Address:    0xb3000
Identifier:      mdworker32
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       i386 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [352]

Date/Time:       2013-01-04 21:41:43.007 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C3012)
Report Version:  8

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9524b7d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   CoreFoundation                  0x9a436599 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
2   CoreFoundation                  0x9a43bf7f __CFRunLoopRun + 1247
3   CoreFoundation                  0x9a43b63a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378
4   CoreFoundation                  0x9a44b061 CFRunLoopRun + 129
5   mdworker32                      0x000bcd14
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x98282725 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9524e9ae kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x957dd7a9 _dispatch_mach_notify_source_init + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9524e0ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x956c3e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x956abcca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9524e0ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x956c3e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x956abcca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9524e0ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x956c3e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x956abcca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9524b7d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   liblaunch.dylib                 0x934cae58
2   liblaunch.dylib                 0x934c968e bootstrap_look_up3 + 78
3   liblaunch.dylib                 0x934c9862 bootstrap_look_up2 + 77
4   IOKit                           0x95792146 _pm_connect + 108
5   IOKit                           0x957936b6 IOPMConnectionGetSystemCapabilities + 38
6   ATS                             0x903c42ff FOLazyInitialize + 83
7   ATS                             0x9040368a FOGetFontFamilyFromName + 31
8   QD                              0x912aafc2 GetFNum + 17
9   HIToolbox                       0x90670a80 HLTBGetFontNumber + 24
10  HIToolbox                       0x906706c6 SetCustomizedFields + 853
11  HIToolbox                       0x906701a0 InitIntlValue + 70
12  CarbonCore                      0x97d331fc IntlIsInitIntlValueDone + 40
13  CarbonCore                      0x97d32b13 SMInitIntlSpec + 1550
14  CarbonCore                      0x97d321d2 LMGetIntlSpec + 69
15  CarbonCore                      0x97db023f FWMapScript + 11
16  CarbonCore                      0x97db021a FillParseTable + 110
17  Microsoft Office                0x00826d25 OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 493228
18  Microsoft Office                0x00826065 OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 489964
19  Microsoft Office                0x0082616e OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 490229
20  Microsoft Office                0x008d215a OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 1194721
21  Microsoft Office                0x007c3c5b OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 87522
22  Microsoft Office                0x007c05dc OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 73571
23  Microsoft Office                0x007c21ca OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 80721
24  Microsoft Office                0x007be0f6 OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 64125
25  Microsoft Office                0x007bf13c OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 68291
26  Microsoft Office                0x007ae78c OfficeImporterPluginFactory + 275
27  mdworker32                      0x000ba98d
28  mdworker32                      0x000b8d33
29  mdworker32                      0x000b9f38
30  mdworker32                      0x000be8c0
31  libsystem_c.dylib               0x956c1557 _pthread_start + 344
32  libsystem_c.dylib               0x956abcee thread_start + 34

Binary Images:
           0xb3000 -           0x10bff3  mdworker32 (707.3) <CA1864D8-D232-3B85-B938-9D3E9DA95AB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker32
          0x7ad000 -           0x9c5ff2  com.microsoft.MDImporter.Office (12.3.0 - 12.3.0) <20AF2AA6-832F-4CA8-B13F-CD260F2A6E96> /Library/Spotlight/Microsoft Office.mdimporter/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Office
        0x903c3000 -         0x90438ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (332) <95206704-F9C9-33C4-AF25-FE9890E160B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
        0x90602000 -         0x909e5ff3  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.0) <5A312E41-9940-363E-B891-90C4672E6850> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
        0x91256000 -         0x912f6ff7  com.apple.QD (3.42) <1B8307C6-AFA8-312E-BA5B-679070EF2CA1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
        0x934c7000 -         0x934cefff  liblaunch.dylib (442.26.2) <310C99F8-0811-314D-9BB9-D0ED6DFA024B> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
        0x95239000 -         0x95253ffc  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.20.9) <561E35E5-E32E-3BFB-9E8B-C977BA6C4F85> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x956ab000 -         0x95768feb  libsystem_c.dylib (825.25) <B1F6916A-F558-38B5-A18C-D9733625FDC9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
        0x95770000 -         0x957d8ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.1) <12C97562-CBBD-3255-A998-28A341128FC8> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
        0x957d9000 -         0x957ebff7  libdispatch.dylib (228.23) <86EF7D45-2D97-3465-A449-95038AE5DABA> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
        0x97d06000 -         0x9800bff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1037.3 - 1037.3) <4571EDDC-704A-3FB1-B9A6-59870AA6165F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
        0x98280000 -         0x98282fff  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <05D6FF2A-F09B-309D-95F7-7AF10259C707> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
        0x9a404000 -         0x9a5ecff3  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.12) <E939CEA0-493C-3233-9983-5070981BB350> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

When I run the above mentioned SUDO command I get

```
/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Add-Ins/Solver.xlam
/Volumes/Not Encrypted/Backups.backupdb/clamont’s MacBook Pro/2012-12-04-080942/Macintosh HD/Users/clamont/Library/Calendars/Calendar Sync Changes/11EDF221-B949-4881-9815-2E00E96A4CA2.tmp
/Volumes/Backup/Backups.backupdb/Chris’s MacBook Pro/2012-12-05-033251/Macintosh HD/Users/clamont/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WritingPCIDrivers/agp_device/agp_device.html
```

Based on the "access denied" error and that I've only backed up 3GB of data within 30 minutes on a firewire port makes me think something is broken.

Can anyone tell me where to go next in troubleshooting this?

---

Update: [I found an article](http://www.princeton.edu/~jcjb/docs/osx_error_fix/) that says I should modify system.sb (located in /System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles) to include:

```
(allow mach-lookup (global-name "com.apple.ls.boxd"))

(allow mach-lookup (local-name "com.apple.ls.boxd"))
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on and if I'm lowering security in any way at all?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a simple restart into safe mode can fix this.

(Source: [Fixing sandboxd: mdworker deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd error in OSX 10.8.2 (and other versions)](http://web.archive.org/web/20121212180752/https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ejcjb/docs/osx_error_fix/))

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in the article you link to is different then the Microsoft Office error.  com.apple.ls.boxd is not involved in your particular error.

I found your posting however because I received the identical sandbox errors being reported for both Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel.  I was doing a new Time Machine backup so the issue may be identical, but did not think to actually check whether the sandbox errors were limited to while I was backing up.  If it helps the backup failed.

I called apple and their recommendation was to restart to the recovery drive and then use the utilities to reset the ACL permissions.  This has now been done and I am back up running Console to check for further errors and yes, I am still getting the same report.  Noticeably this time the sandbox error replicated without Time Machine even running so it appears to be a Microsoft Office issue not directly connected to Time Machine.

I am sending the new log to apple and will see what they say.

Comment: > I am sending the new log to apple and will see what they say. Hi Sean, Do you remember if you got a response from apple? I'm running into the same issue in 10.8.4, and I'm running out of options.